# Do I need to install dependencies one-by-one? (and if so, why?)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm porting a node/Express app to Heroku, and it keeps crashing. The log first said, "Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'" I then (re-)installed mongoose. Then it crashed with "Error: Cannot find module 'moment'"

I `require` mongoose, moment, etc. in my app. Isn't `npm install` by itself supposed to take care of the dependencies, or do I additionally have to add all these dependencies, one-by-one, to the `package.json` file, in addition to `npm install`?  Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the older version of NPM (5.0.0 or earlier), you had to add --save as a flag to the npm install as:

```
npm i package-name --save
```

And it would add it to your package.json. As of 5.0.0 and later, it automatically adds it to the package file.

To answer your question, yes, you will have to add them one at a time for now. And keep in mind what I said before, because if you are using an older version of NPM, make sure you use --save when you are installing so you don't have to do extra work :-)

Comment: The 'i' in the command above is the shortened way of doing install, if you didn't know.